# Solaris11 and complex networking: no routing

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, routing, solaris

I have one server with solaris11.4,two nics
I use it for testing,learning,etc..
I have one network,the classical 192.168.0.0/24
But for virtual machines i want to use another network 10.2.0.0/24
So I follow this procedure

a)First I have create a bridge with net1 and net0,otherwise net1 start "disconnected"

```
dladm create-bridge -l net0 -l net1 bridge1
```

b)Then I configure ipv4 addr for net1

```
ipadm create-ip net1
ipadm create-addr -T static -a 10.2.0.1 net1
```

ipadm and dladm report no errors

c)Then I run on solaris11 server isc-dhcp,and isc-dns
All works fine,tested,I can resolve external hostnames
and dhcp assing address

d)I have installed VirtualBox,machines with bridged-networking point to net1

e)I have configured firewall with nat

```
#Vars
ext_if="net0"
int_if="net1"
virt_if="vnic0"
ext_net="192.168.0.0/24"
int_net="10.2.0.0/24"
webports="{443, 80}"

##  make IP reassembly work
set reassemble yes no-df

## ignore loopback traffic
set skip on lo0

# block everything unless told otherwise
# and send TCP-RST/ICMP unreachable
# for every packet which gets blocked
block return in log all
pass out all

# accept incoming SSH connections
pass in proto tcp to any port 2122

# accept dhcp connections
pass in proto udp to any port 67:69
pass in proto tcp to any port 67:69

# accept dns connections
pass in proto udp to any port 53
pass in proto tcp to any port 53

# accept webeservers SSH connections
pass in proto tcp to $ext_if port 8888:8889
pass in proto tcp to $ext_if port $webports

# accept icmp
pass in proto icmp all

## allow all connections initiated from this system,
## including DHCP requests
pass out

#nat
pass out on net0 from $int_net  to any nat-to (net0)
```

f)With routeadm i have enabled routing and ip-forwarding.

Now the "result"

I can ping 10.2.0.0/24 from 192.168.0.0/24 OK
I can ping 192.168.0.0/24 from 10.2.0.0/24 vm's OK
I can ping external address(google.de,etc) from 10.2.0.0/24 vm's OK
I cannot connect with any protocol from the vm's!! NOT OK
Of course I have checked route with netstat -rn and said 10.2.0.1 default
(correct).
But telnet,links,yum and any kind of connection fail!
Only ping and dns resolution works(sic!)
What to check?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution found: firewall too restrictive.
I use this /etc/firewall/pf.conf.,works fine without problem

```
# Vars
ext_if="net0"
int_if="net1"
ext_net="192.168.0.0/24"
int_net="10.2.0.0/24"
webports="{443, 80}"

##  make IP reassembly work
set reassemble yes no-df

## ignore loopback traffic
set skip on lo0

# block everything unless told otherwise
# and send TCP-RST/ICMP unreachable
# for every packet which gets blocked
block return in log all
pass out all

# Pass
pass in on $int_if proto tcp from $ext_net to any keep state
pass in on $int_if proto udp from $ext_net to any keep state
pass in on $int_if proto tcp from $int_net to any keep state
pass in on $int_if proto udp from $int_net to any keep state

# accept incoming SSH connections
pass in proto tcp from any to $ext_if port 22

# accept dhcp connections
pass in proto udp to any port 67:69
pass in proto tcp to any port 67:69

# accept dns connections
pass in proto udp to any port 53
pass in proto tcp to any port 53

# accept webeservers connections
pass in proto tcp to $ext_if port $webports

# accept icmp
pass in proto icmp all

## allow all connections initiated from this system,
## including DHCP requests
pass out

#nat
pass out on net0 from $int_net to any nat-to (net0)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include more detail, including the exact steps required to solve the problem. Otherwise future visitors with your same question won't be helped.

Comment: It might help others to talk about the problem solving process, what the actual problem was and how you ended up fixing it. Firewalls being too restrictive is a problem, or maybe even a symptom, but is only a solution to "the firewall being too lax"

Comment: Right,I edit now,I cannot make this yesterday because too busy with network pratice